# Fiddler not seeing transactions made by application to SOAP web service

Tags: c#, soap, proxy, fiddler

Fiddler doesnt show requests/responses to SOAP Web Service made by C# application.

I have an application thats communicating with http://servername/MyApi.asmx

When i browse to this endpoint in a browser it shows up in Fiddler, however when i make a request via the application it doesnt show in fiddler. Any ideas?

Comment: See if there are any TCP packets (TLS) and check version.  The TLS has to occur before the HTTP Request is shown on fiddler.

Answer (score 0):

I add this to my app.config which resolved the issue. Seems by default the application wont use the windows system proxy so you need to specify the fiddler proxy URL.

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy>
      <proxy autoDetect="false" bypassonlocal="false" proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" usesystemdefault="false" />
    </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```